# Op amp amplifier with capacitor

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, amplifier, circuit-analysis, inverting-amplifier

What happens when the resistors of an op amp amplifier circuit are replaced with capacitors? Or inductors?

What is the frequency response of such an arrangement?

Comment: Op-amps become active filters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications

Comment: @filo -  Since the general equation for a opamp amplifier circuit involves the ratio of impedances, how will replacing with capacitors affect amplification

Comment: @Ashwin Replace and see.

Comment: Capacitors are impedances at AC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at specific cases. Start with a standard inverting op amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd91OI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If Vin is a DC voltage, the output will be a DC voltage with (approximately) Vout = -(R2/R1)Vin. The same holds true (approximately) for low-frequency AC signals, where "low-frequency" depends on the op amp.

Now let's try

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgSrpE.png)</sup>

In this case, the effect of *bias currents* on the input become critical. Every real amplifier will either sink or source small currents at its inputs. For the + input, this is not a problem, since it goes to ground. For the - input, though, the current has no place to go, and will slowly charge up the capacitor, and cause the input voltage (+ input minus - input) to ramp up. The result is that the output will ramp up or down and quite quickly saturate at the upper or lower bounds of the op amp's capability.

In the case of ideal inductors, it gets a bit trickier, but not any better. An ideal inductor has zero resistance, so the "obvious" response for DC input is zero volts output. For AC, the circuit ought to work more or less like a resistor circuit, with the gain set by the ratio of the inductor values, where Z = 2 pi L. However, given the phase shift associated with the inductors will almost certainly cause the op amp to break into oscillation.

Comment: How is it that the output with an inductor to DC is zero. Suppose if the input is let's say 5V the voltage across the inductor will be 5V in an inverting configuration. So some current must flow through the inductor at the input and the same must flow in the feedback inductors as well. So there must be some output voltage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding the capacitors, what will happen if a bias current return path is provided?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same equations you would use with resistors (e.g. gain = -Rf/Ri) but replace the R's with Z's.  So an inverting amplifier gain would be -Zf/Zi.  Obviously, now the Z's have a frequency dependence.

Comment: Won't the frequency dependent terms get canceled out

Comment: @BobU What would a bode plot look like. The transfer function is then just -Ci/Cf for two caps